# Как изменить тему для Spinner?

Tags: android

В моем приложении меняется фон у Activity, в зависимости от действий происходящих внутри приложения. Тема приложения — Holo.Light. Фон активити может быть темным и светлым. В этом активити имеется Spinner. Проблема заключается в том, что когда фон темный, Spinner начинает сливаться с фоном. Связанно это с тем, что у него установлена высокая прозрачность.

Возможно ли как-то изменять тему для одного View программно? То есть, чтобы когда фон светлый, пусть и для Spinner-а будет использоваться стиль из Holo.Light. А вот когда фон становится темным, нужно чтобы Spinner использовал стиль из темной темы Holo. Как это реализовать?

Comment: вам можно создать два разных стиля для spinner, затем есть два варианта:  
1- создать две кастомных темы, унаследовавшись от Holo и там применить стиль для спиннер
2 - динамически задавать тстиль для спиннер

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, Вы не можете применить тему для одного контрола. Тема используется для всей Activity целиком.

Как вариант - это уйти от использования контролом темы активити, путем написания собственных двух стилей (по одному для каждой темы) и менять их программно.

Почитать про темы и стили [тут](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)
 / [Похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110853/applying-holo-light-theme-to-single-controls)
 / [Возможное решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5052401/1616443)

Comment: В моем случае подошел вариант с ContextThemeWrapper. Но все равно спасибо за ответ!